# Is there a simple expression for this generating function that is almost like the binomial formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

This is a curiosity I when looking at the binomial theorem. Say you have an ordinary generating function $\displaystyle\sum_{n,m\geq 0}\binom{n}{m}x^ny^m$. This looks kind of like $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}x^iy^{n-i}=(x+y)^n$.

Is there likewise a nice expression for the first generating function?

Comment: Yep. Write it as an outer sum over $n$ together with an inner sum over $m$.

Comment: How are you defining ${n\choose m}$ for $m>n$?

Comment: @Chris: the only reasonable definition is that it be equal to $0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course,
$$
  \sum_{n,m \ge 0} \binom{n}{m} x^n y^m = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} y^m = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n (1+y)^n  = \frac{1}{1-x(1+y)}
$$

Comment: Oh, that's very nice. Thank you.

Comment: doesnt this over $m$ too much? ie $m=0,m=0,1,m=0,1,2,$ etc